# Implementing Lookup Table in PIC16F1782

Tags: pic, lookup-tables

I'm Using PIC16F1782 and trying to implement a retlw lookup table. I've written this code relating to **microchip AN556 (Implementing a Table Read)** But is doesn't work. I've simulated this code using **MPLAB X IDE v3.05** and found that **MOVLW HIGH IF_TABLE** puts 0x80 to the WREG that seems to be wrong. Then PC would get a wrong value and when I call IF_TABLE, the program goes to a wrong place. I would appreciate it if you could help me.

```
ORG 0H
GOTO MAIN
;simple ISR for TIMER0 OverFlow
ORG 0004H
BTFSS INTCON,2
RETFIE
MOVLW 0X01
XORWF PORTA,F
BCF INTCON,2
RETFIE


MAIN
;OSCON,DACCON and portA configurations
BANKSEL OSCCON
MOVLW B'11110000'
MOVWF OSCCON
BANKSEL DACCON0
MOVLW B'10110000'
MOVWF DACCON0
BANKSEL OPTION_REG
MOVLW B'10000001'
MOVWF OPTION_REG
BANKSEL INTCON
MOVLW B'10100000'
MOVWF INTCON
BANKSEL TRISA
BANKSEL PORTA ;
CLRF PORTA ;Init PORTA
BANKSEL LATA ;Data Latch
CLRF LATA ;
BANKSEL ANSELA ;
CLRF ANSELA ;digital I/O
BANKSEL TRISA ;
MOVLW B'00000000'
MOVWF TRISA
BANKSEL PORTA
BSF PORTA,0

CLRF 0X27
CLRF 0X28
;the problem is in RPT loop
RPT:

MOVF 0X27,W
MOVWF 0X28
MOVLW LOW IF_TABLE

ADDWF 0X28,F

MOVLW HIGH IF_TABLE
BTFSC STATUS,C
ADDLW 1

MOVWF PCLATH

MOVF 0X28,W

CALL IF_TABLE

BANKSEL DACCON1
MOVWF DACCON1

INCF 0X27,F

GOTO RPT


IF_TABLE:

MOVWF PCL
RETLW D'126'
RETLW D'128'
RETLW D'131'
RETLW D'136'
.
.
.
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To point to the actual slot in the table you have to add one to the index:

```
RPT:

MOVF 0X27,W
MOVWF 0X28
INCF 0x28,F         ; add here
MOVLW LOW IF_TABLE
```

Also, after the BANKSEL DACCON1 you need to switch back to bank zero

```
BANKSEL DACCON1
MOVWF DACCON1
BANKSEL 0X27     ; switch back here
INCF 0X27,F
```

Comment: The problem was that offset should be between 1 to 255. Actually I added some codes that prevents 0x27 from being zero.(INCF 0x28,F won't solve problem completely because as soon as 0x27 reach to 0xff value, the 0x28 will be zero and the program stays at movwf pcl line)